# Passing arrays in awk function

Tags: awk

I want to write a function which accepts two arguments one is a constant values and another is an array. The function finds the index of the element in the arrays and returns it.I want to call this function with multiple arrays just as below what I have tried.

```
 BEGIN{
a[1]=2;
a[2]=4;
a[3]=3;
b[1]=4;
b[2]=2;
b[3]=6;
c[1]=5;
c[2]=1;
c[3]=6;
arr[1]=a;
arr[2]=b;
arr[3]=c
}
function pos(val,ar[])  {
for (m=1;m<=length(ar);m++) { if (val == ar[m] )
     return m;
else continue }
}

{for( k=1;k<=NF;k++) { for(l=1;l<=length(arr);l++) { print "pos=" pos($i,arr[l])}  } }
```

but I am getting errors :

```
fatal: attempt to use array `a' in a scalar context
```

Looking at the code can anyone tell me how can I achieve what I am trying to achieve using awk. The challenge I have here is to assign and array as an element to another array as in `arr[1]=a` and passing the the array as a parameter by referencing it with its index as in `pos($i,arr[l]` . I dont know how to make these statements syntactically and functionally correct in awk .

the input is :

```
2 4 6 
3 5 6 
1 2 5
```

and in the out put the code should return the position of the value read from the file if it is present in any of the arrays defined

output:

```
1 1 3
    6
  2 1
```

in first line of output  indexed of corresponding elements in the array a b and c have been returned respectively .  1  is index of 2 in a , 1 is index of 4 in b and 3 is index of 6 in c and so on for the upcoming lines in the input file.

Comment: Yes, it is expected. As you can't assign any array without its value to any other variable or array. Please post your sample Input_file and expected output in post so that we could help you in same.

Comment: I see you have edited your post, please add some more example of what is your requirement, to get help on it please.

Comment: I want to write and code in awk that will read values from an input files and return its index values in three different arrays a , b and c . I have tried above code but I am not confident about it.

Comment: ok, please add appropriate examples in your question so that we could help you on same.

Comment: You mis-spelled `length` in `lenght(arr)` and never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. `else continue` is doing nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I truly don't understand what it is you're trying to do (especially why an input of `2` produces the index from `a` but not the index from `b` while an input of `4` does the reverse) but to create a multi-dimensional array `arr[][]` from `a[]`, `b[]`, and `c[]` with GNU awk (the only awk that supports true multi-dimensional arrays) would be:

```
for (i in a) arr[1][i] = a[i]
for (i in b) arr[2][i] = b[i]
for (i in c) arr[3][i] = c[i]
```

not just `arr[1] = a`, etc. Note that you're storing a copy of the contents of `a[]` in `arr[1][]`, not a reference to `a[]`, so if `a[]` changes then `arr[1][]` won't. What you might want to do instead (again GNU awk only) is store the sub-array names in `arr[]` and then access them through the builtin variable `SYMTAB` (see the man page), e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{
    split("2 4 3",a)
    split("4 2 6",b)
    split("5 1 6",c)

    arr[1] = "a"
    arr[2] = "b"
    arr[3] = "c"

    prtArr(arr)
}

function prtArr(arr,    i,subArrName) {
    for (i=1; i in arr; i++) {
        subArrName = arr[i]
        printf "arr[%d] -> %s[] =\n", i, subArrName
        prtSubArr(SYMTAB[subArrName])
    }
}

function prtSubArr(subArr,      j) {
    for (j=1; j in subArr; j++) {
        print "\t" subArr[j]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
arr[1] -> a[] =
        2
        4
        3
arr[2] -> b[] =
        4
        2
        6
arr[3] -> c[] =
        5
        1
        6
```

Now `arr[]` is no longer a multi-dimensional array, it's just an array of array name strings, and the contents of `a[]` are only stored in 1 place (in `a[]`) and just referenced from `SYMTAB[]` indexed by the contents of `arr[N]` rather than copied into `arr[N][]`.